# I Want to store the resulted data in a variable for further use in sails js (mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, sails.js

i want to fetch the price from the database to store in order model,
here is my code

```
newOrder: function(req,res){
    var data = req.body;
    const orderNo = data.orderNo;
    const user = data.user;
    const business = data.business;
    const inventory = data.inventory;
    const price = Inventory.find({id: data.inventory}).exec(function(err,record){ return record.price});
    const address = data.address;
    const quantity = data.quantity;
    const contactNumber = data.contactNumber;

    Order.create({
      orderNo: orderNo,
      user: user,
      business: business,
      inventory: inventory,
      price: price,
      address: address,
      quantity: quantity,
      contactNumber: contactNumber
      }).then(function(result){
      res.ok(result);
    });
  },
```

i know it is not correct , but i don't know how to do that,
the inner query is not returning anything,
i want to store the resulted data in variable for further use.
please Help

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
newOrder: function(req,res){
    var data = req.body;
    const orderNo = data.orderNo;
    const user = data.user;
    const business = data.business;
    const inventory = data.inventory;
    const address = data.address;
    const quantity = data.quantity;
    const contactNumber = data.contactNumber;

    Inventory.findOne({id: data.inventory})
    .then(function(record) {
        // Price is available here as record.price,
        // do whatever you want with it
        return Order.create({
            orderNo: orderNo,
            user: user,
            business: business,
            inventory: inventory,
            price: record.price,
            address: address,
            quantity: quantity,
            contactNumber: contactNumber
        });
    })
    .then(function(createdOrder) {
        res.ok(createdOrder);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error ar newOrder:", err);
        return res.serverError(err);
    })
}
```

basically just fetch the inventory record first, and then you can use it in the `Order` query. I also swapped `Inventory.find` to `.findOne()` since it seemed like that's how you intended to use it.